# Remove extra right margin when using alert-dismissible

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Adding `alert-dismissible` adds a margin to the whole alert box, which I don't like:

```
 <div class="alert alert-dark mb-5 alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <div class="media">
            <img src="https://dummyimage.com/45x45/000/fff" class="align-self-top mr-3" alt="logo">
            <div class="media-body">
                <strong>Hello!</strong><br />
                Bla bla bla
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>

        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 mt-3">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a08tdmw7/), the video doesn't take the full width of the alert, but stays too far from the right side. Removing `alert-dismissible` fixes this, but I want this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reset its padding???

```css
.alert.alert-dismissible {
    padding-right: 1.25rem;
}
```

If you're building custom theme with *Bootstrap SASS* files, you can do something like:

```
.alert {
    &.alert-dismissible {
        padding-right: @alert-padding-x;
    }
}
```

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/05puear4/2